# aws-cdk prop.vpc Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

trying to get the VPC values from prop but getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vpcId')" when I do "cdk synth EksAsgStack".
**The code from bin file is**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { EksVpcStack } from '../lib/eks-vpc-stack';
import { EksAsgStack } from '../lib/eks-asg-stack'

const app = new cdk.App();

// get cdk environment
const env = {account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION, environment: process.env.AWS_ENV};

console.log('accountId: ', env.account);
console.log('region: ', env.region);
console.log( 'depl: ', env.environment)

const vpcStack = new EksVpcStack(
  app,
  "EksVpcStack",
  {
    prefixName: "EksCdk",
    cidr: "172.29.0.0/16",
    maxAzs: 3,
    env: env,
    depl: `${process.env.AWS_ENV}`,
    description: "EksCdk VPC Stack"
  }
);

const asgStack = new EksAsgStack(
  app,
  "EksAsgStack",
  {
    prefixName: "EksCdk",
    depl: `${process.env.AWS_ENV}`,
    **vpc: vpcStack.vpc,**
    env: env
  }
```

And the relevant snippets from the stack file
**Import**

```
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
```

**Interface for props**

```
interface VpcStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  vpc: ec2.IVpc;
  prefixName: string,
  depl: string,
}
```

**The class**

```
type hexport class EksAsgStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: VpcStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const securityGroupName = `${props?.prefixName}-${props?.depl}-asgSg`;ere
```

**And the construct**

```
      const SecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'securityGroupName', {
        vpc: props.vpc,
        allowAllOutbound: true,
        securityGroupName: securityGroupName,
        description: 'security group for asg',
      });
```

npm run build is clear with no errors but the prop is not working
cdk version 2.97.0 (build d7cf3be)

cdk synth should run and get the vpc prop

Comment: The relevant bit is whether your `EksVpcStack` has a `vpc` field.

Comment: Thanks gshpychka
in the construct there is vpc: props.vpc, and in the interface props vpc: ec2.IVpc;

Comment: Your class has to have a `vpc` field - it doesn't at the moment.